# Seam in periodic rendered mesh in Mayavi

Tags: rendering, mesh, mayavi

I am trying to map data on a sphere, but I can't get rid of a seam where it wraps around at azimuthal angle phi = 2*pi. I wrote a simple example to show the problem:

```
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np
from import_field_map import import_field_map

data = np.empty([24, 25])
for ldx, line in enumerate(data):
    for cdx, col in enumerate(line):
        data[ldx, cdx] = ldx

phi_range = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, 25)
theta_range = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 24)
phis, thetas = np.meshgrid(phi_range, theta_range)

x = np.cos(thetas) * np.cos(phis)
y = np.cos(thetas) * np.sin(phis)
z = np.sin(thetas)

mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1, 1, 1), fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(400, 300))
mlab.clf()
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, scalars=data, colormap='jet')
mlab.view()
mlab.show()
```

[image]

It looks as though Mayavi is not able to calculate GL vertex normals at those points, because it does not know that the mesh is periodic.

Answer (score 0):

I just found one solution that does not solve the root of the problem (unless it's not a problem and I'm just using Mayavi wrong).

By using `scipy.ndimage.zoom` I can up-sample my data array and thus increase the number of rendered faces. Then, the difference between face and vertex normals becomes so small that the seam is not noticeable anymore.